# Firebird 2.1 database is missing the monitor tables can they be added?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.1

I found some Firebird 2.1 databases which are missing the monitor tables ie(MON$ATTACHMENTS).
Is there anyway of adding them?

I tried to insert them, but they appeared as normal tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Features like monitoring tables depend on the On-Disk-Structure (ODS) version of the Firebird database. Your database is likely still an old ODS version (11.0 or older, eg Firebird 2.0 or older). You need to backup and restore the database to upgrade it to the ODS of Firebird 2.1 (ODS 11.1). This will add the monitoring tables.

This is also documented in the 2.1.7 release notes, section [Monitoring tables](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes217.html#rnfb210-mon):

> Virtual monitoring tables exist only in ODS 11.1 (and higher) databases, so a migration via backup/restore is required in order to use this feature.

If you are upgrading, consider upgrading to Firebird 2.5 instead.

Comment: Mark, As always you gave the right solution.

Thanks again for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

alternativly, they are only visible if you connect as sysdba or database owner

Comment: Monitoring tables are available for all users, but they will just see information about their current connection (at least: in Firebird 2.5. nor sure about 2.1).